# How can I check if more two strings have n words in common (Python)?

Tags: python, string, compare

I have two string looking (for example) like this:

```
string1 = "Password age (minimum) is set to 60"
string2 = "age of password is set to 60 or less!"
```

(In my task there are way more string ofc but these to are just
to show you my problem)

So now I want to compare if those 2 string >= 3 words in common.

So the output would be something like this:

```
string1 & string2 have 3 or more words in common:

["Password", "is", "set", "to", "age", "60"]
```

Comment: Split each string into words, make sets of the words and intersect them.

Comment: You might want to clarify what should happen if there are duplicate words.

Comment: @sj95126 they can just be put in the same array. filtering for duplicates n stuff isn't part of this question.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could look like this

```py
set(string1.split()).intersection(string2.split())
```

which gives you a set of words that occur in both strings. Keep in mind that this approach is fairly naive, in that it assumes that all words are separated by spaces (which is not the case for words like *don't* and also for punctuation). You might want to look into a more sophisticated tokenizer to achieve more accurate results (e.g. [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "Password age (minimum) is set to 60".split()
string2 = "age of password is set to 60 or less!".split()


newName = ""

for letter in string1:
    if letter in string2:
       newName = letter
       print(newName)
```

If want to see remaining item then use no in instead of in"""

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would be to use sets, and the `&` intersection operator.
However, there's many ways this could be done.

```py
def countShared(s1, s2):
    # set the strings to lowercase 
    s1 = s1.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()

    # convert the string to a list, split by the space character
    s1List = s1.split(" ")
    s2List = s2.split(" ")

    # we can get the shared words by converting the lists to sets and 
    # use the & operator, which gets the 'intersection' (aka the shared items) from both sets
    sharedWords = set(s1List) & set(s2List)

    # to make it easier to use, we turn it back into a list
    return list(sharedWords)
```

For your example, you would then run it like this:

```py
string1 = "Password age (minimum) is set to 60"
string2 = "age of password is set to 60 or less!"

outWords = countShared(string1, string2)

print("string1 & string2 have " + str(len(outWords)) + " words in common:")
print(", ".join(outWords))
```

This gives the output:

```
string1 & string2 have 6 words in common:
age, set, 60, to, password, is
```